# Where is the unhandled promise rejection? How can I avoid it?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, promise

Working with Node and [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) to pull queries for five different databases to de-dupe against each other and merge into a more unified schema.

My process follows this algorithm:

create a shared pool by calling this function:

```
const getPoolConnection = async () => {
  try {
    let pool = await mssql.connect(`mssql://${username}:${password}@${server}/`);
    return pool;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

This function creates the pool and returns it to the calling function. `username`, `password`, and `server` are imported and scoped to this file.

Then we query each database and assign the result to a property on an object. This is accomplished via a `forEach` loop:

```
lists.forEach(list => {
  fullData[list] = db.queryDatabase(pool, customers[list].query).catch(err => console.error(err));
})
```

which calls this function:

```
const queryDatabase = async (pool, query) => {
  try {
    let result = await pool.request().query(query);
    // console.log(result);
    return result.recordset, pool;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

now in order to keep post-processing from occuring before all database calls return data, I've wrapped the entire set of calls in a `Promise.all()` call in the main `index.js` file. This is the calling funciton:

```
const { customers } = require('./query');
const util = require('./util');
const db = require('./db');

fullData = {};

(async () => {
  let pool = await db.getPoolConnection();
  let lists = Object.keys(customers);
  Promise.all(
    lists.forEach(list => {
      fullData[list] = db.queryDatabase(pool, customers[list].query).catch(err => console.error(err));
    })
  )
    .then(results, pool => {
      console.dir(results);
      db.closePoolConnection(pool);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
})();
```

What I don't understand is this error that occurs when attempting to debug the application:

> (node:18908) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined warning.js:18
>       at Function.all ()
>       at c:\Users\rutherfordc\Documents\GitHub\migration-plus\index.js:10:11
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7) (node:18908) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) warning.js:18
>   (node:18908) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are
>   not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit
>   code. warning.js:18 (node:18908) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
>   ReferenceError: results is not defined warning.js:18
>       at c:\Users\rutherfordc\Documents\GitHub\migration-plus\index.js:15:11
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7) (node:18908) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) needs an array. So you could do something like this:

```
fullData = [];

(async () => {
  let pool = await db.getPoolConnection();
  let lists = Object.keys(customers);
  lists.forEach(list => {
    fullData.push(db.queryDatabase(pool, customers[list].query).catch(err => console.error(err));
  }));

  Promise.all(fullData)
    .then((results, pool) => {
      console.dir(results);
      db.closePoolConnection(pool);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
})();
```

**Update:**

Also as J. Pichardo suggested in his answer, in case of multiple parameters, the parameters should be enclosed in parentheses.
[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Okay! let's see that in action! Testing now.

Answer (score 1):

The error is non-logical but syntactical, the following lines in the main function

```
.then(results, pool => {
  console.dir(results);
  db.closePoolConnection(pool);
})
```

The arguments of the arrow function should be surrounded by parentheses, like:

```
.then((results, pool) => {
  console.dir(results);
  db.closePoolConnection(pool);
})
```

> ReferenceError: results is not defined

So, the `then` is looking for a `results` variable and since it is an `async` function when it crashes it will be a `UnhandledPromiseRejection`.

#### Update:

As the other answer says `Promise.all` receives either multiple promises or an array of promises, so you could do something like:

```
var fullData = lists.map(list => db.queryDatabase(pool, customers[list].query).catch(err => console.error(err)));

Promise.all(fullData).then(...)
```